# Play 1000 Frames Per Second in Blender

Tags: python, animation, scripting

I am trying to animate using Blender. I want to play 1000 frames per second, but Blender only seems to allow a maximum of 120. I am not super conscious about quality but I have thousand different states that I want to be played on screen in one second. Any suggestions?

I pick any 120 equal interval frames.

I'm okay if the answer requires Blender Python, too.

Comment: is this for a physics simulation/scientific measurements?

Comment: Just so you know, that means you'll be getting a frame played once per millisecond. Your brain can only react to something between 300-400 milliseconds(so your brain will have missed 300 frames when still processing 1). Also, your monitor will have to have a 1000 GHz refresh rate (which I don't think exists).

Comment: zeffim something like that. or more of playing around, scientifically.
I am asking can I do it with blender? If I can do it with blender and if my monitor cannot handle it, what will happen? @Charles, just normal display or error?

Comment: If your monitor can't handle(which I'm pretty sure it can't), it just won't display the 940 frames it's missing. It'll display every 16th frame.

Comment: Great, that does not matter then. Is it possible in python? Don't take me stupid to do unnecessary thing. Suppose things are that way. and I have to achieve it.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. I wasn't trying to discourage it, I was just stating some of the technical limitations.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure if this accomplishes what you want but,

In the render tab, under "frame rate:" choose "custom".
Then you will get 2 more options

1. FPS
2. Framerate base

In FPS input 100, and in Framerate base input 0.1.
It should now say "Custom (1000)" in your framerate settings.